# Electron app do not start but electron-builder (dist) is ok

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Can't figure what's wrong in my electron project. Starting with `electron .` will fail with one native module (pkcs11js). See image :

[image]

But running `npm run dist` will build installer just fine, and running this installer work's fine and app is starting/workin like charm !

```
PS C:\Users\esa\devel\netauth\client> npm run dist

> Yubiconn2@1.0.0 dist C:\Users\esa\devel\netauth\client
> electron-builder -w --x64

  • electron-builder  version=21.2.0 os=10.0.18362
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=pkcs11js@1.0.18 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=6.0.7 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • building        target=nsis file=dist\Yubiconn2 Setup 1.0.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  • building block map  blockMapFile=dist\Yubiconn2 Setup 1.0.0.exe.blockmap
```

and this was fine before today when I upgraded all outdated npm packages up-to-date. And nodejs too. This is Win10 env. My OsX env will work without any problem.

I have tried :

- `rm -rf node_modules; npm install`
- `npm rebuild`
- even installing `electron-rebuild` and running `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild`

I understand `electron-builder` will rebuild all native dependencies for distribution. How to make same with development env (`electron .` or `npm start`)

Comment: Try running `electron-builder install-app-deps`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update node.js. See the part of your error about NODE_MODULE_VERSION

This explains the value of NODE_MODULE_VERSION https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/#ref-1